# How to set colorcolumn for the whole screen except 80 column?

Tags: vim

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
"====[ Make the 81st column stand out ]====================
let &colorcolumn=join(range(1,80),",")."80,".join(range(81,9999),",")
set background=dark
```

But as you can see in the screenshot it slightly dimmed in the right end of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your problem is the the color, not obvious enough, you can highlight the `ColorColumn` group by yourself.

E.g. `hi ColorColumn ctermbg=blue guibg=blue`

After checking the `let ..` line, it seems that you marked all columns as colorcolumn, except the 80th. Because you did `join(..).'80,'...` It turns out `1,2,3...79,8080,81...`. That is, the 80th column will use your normal bg color, and 1-79, 81-9999 will be highlighted by `ColorColumn` group.

Why not thinking in the other way around, only set `colorcolumn` for the 80th?